# How to get access to the default download file path

Tags: java, android, android-afilechooser

I'm trying to open my downloaded files on a specific path (my download folder in the app). Unfortunately, I do not know how to implement this method.I found this way by searching the Internet.

```
 ... } else if (id == R.id.nav_MyDownloads) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("storage/sdcard/pdfs"); // a directory
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));;

}...
```

But when I use `intent`, I see the path of the recent files instead of the path I introduce, please guide me. thank you

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri`, and `"storage/sdcard/pdfs"` is not a valid `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much, instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`  what to use? I think the path is correct?

Comment: where is your download file location?

Comment: There is no requirement that a device have an app that is capable of browsing a directory, and I am not certain what "open my downloaded files" means.

Comment: @g7pro sdcard/pdfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried this to get the directory path ?

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

If I got your question, what you want to achieve is this:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path.getAbsolutePath());
```

path.getAbsolutePath() gives you the Download folder path like this: 
        /storage/emulated/0/Download

Comment: No, I did not use this command
I use only a few lines to get to the folder, You can explain a little more about it?

Comment: I'd recommend you explain what this line does fully. Otherwise, this should have been a comment.

Comment: @Taslim Thank you, I was able to find the route. But I'm going to get the contents of this file. For example, I have 5 PDF files on this path and I want to open it in my program. What should I do now?